# How to merge two nested dictionaries in python, which have same keys and have array type values?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, nested

I need to merge two dictionaries d1 and d2, where:

```
d1 = {0: [array([ 42.9017, -78.6631]), array([ 41.5372, -74.0526]), array([ 39.8017, -89.6437])], 
  1: [array([ 34.7269, -86.5673]), array([ 29.7229, -98.0742])],
  2: [array([  35.9878, -115.1167]), array([  34.0316, -117.6187])],array([  61.6303, -148.9872])]}

d2 = {0: [array([5, 5], dtype=int64), array([44, 44], dtype=int64),array([1, 1], dtype=int64)], 
  1: [array([1, 1], dtype=int64), array([12, 12], dtype=int64), array([1, 1], dtype=int64)],
  2: [array([1, 1], dtype=int64), array([12, 12], dtype=int64), array([1, 1], dtype=int64)]}
```

I need dictionary d3 after merging d1 and d2, such that, 1st value of key:0 of d1 is merged with 1st value of key:0 of d2.

Expecting d3 as:

```
  d3 =  {0: [array([ 42.9017, -78.6631]), array([5, 5], dtype=int64), array([ 41.5372, -74.0526]), array([44, 44], dtype=int64) , array([ 39.8017, -89.6437]), array([1, 1], dtype=int64)], 
  1: [array([ 34.7269, -86.5673]), array([1, 1], dtype=int64), array([ 29.7229, -98.0742]), array([12, 12], dtype=int64)],
  2: [array([  35.9878, -115.1167]),array([1, 1], dtype=int64),array([1, 1], dtype=int64), array([12, 12], dtype=int64), array([  34.0316, -117.6187])],array([1, 1], dtype=int64), array([ 61.6303, -148.9872])]}
```

I have tried multiple approaches, but nothing seems to work appropriately.
Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please post what you have tried; someone may be able to help you fix it.

Comment: could you clarify what you expect d3 to be? you example is short enough that it should be relatively easy.

Comment: @ScottHunter 
I tried this code: 


from copy import deepcopy
Dict1 = d1
Dict2 =  d2
dic = deepcopy(dict1)
print(dict1)
for key in dict2.keys():
    if key in dic:
        dic[key].update(dict2[key])
    else:
        dic[key] = dict2[key]


Output:  This code is not merging values at index level, which is ideally expected

Comment: @AnneAunyme I expect d3 to be a dictionary too ... Yes, this is just a subset of d1 and d2 ... I have 765 values in total within each dictionary

Comment: @Sparsh_ag could you write it? write d3 as you expect it to appear?

Comment: @AnneAunyme I have edited the original question with expected format of d3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question well. You can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to *alternate* between the values from the two dictionaries:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

out = {}
for k in d1.keys() | d2.keys():
    for v1, v2 in zip_longest(d1.get(k, []), d2.get(k, [])):
        out.setdefault(k, [])
        if not v1 is None:
            out[k].append(v1)
        if not v2 is None:
            out[k].append(v2)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    0: [
        array([42.9017, -78.6631]),
        array([5, 5]),
        array([41.5372, -74.0526]),
        array([44, 44]),
        array([39.8017, -89.6437]),
        array([1, 1]),
    ],
    1: [
        array([34.7269, -86.5673]),
        array([1, 1]),
        array([29.7229, -98.0742]),
        array([12, 12]),
        array([1, 1]),
    ],
    2: [
        array([35.9878, -115.1167]),
        array([1, 1]),
        array([34.0316, -117.6187]),
        array([12, 12]),
        array([61.6303, -148.9872]),
        array([1, 1]),
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the two `dict`s have the same keys, and you don't care in which order the elements from `d1` and `d2` values appear in their corresponding `d3` value, then it's as simple as

```
d3 = {k: d1[k]+d2[k] for k in d1}
```